# How do we create a sub-table in a mat-table when clicked on a link in a row using angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-table in which there are values in every row. 
When i click on the data in a row, a new row which contains another mat-table should be added

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called as Master Detail table or Nested Table.
If you want to achieve a Nested Table you can use npm library.
Here is a link to [Nested Table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-nested-data-table).

Here are two stackblitz examples for you.

1. [Simple Nested Table](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-expandable-table-rows)
2. [Ngx Nested  Material Table](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-material-nested-tables)

If you need specific help with your code then post the code along with explanation of what's going wrong or even better create a stackblitz example to help us identify the issue and help you.